# How to effectively manage/host many WCF services for an SOA

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, soa, was

My current architecture is a nice fit for SOA.

The services are written using WCF, and everything is .NET (no interoperability required).

To start off with I was hosting the WCF services inside a Windows Service with ServiceHost.

But now the number of services is growing and I am reconsidering the choice to have them as separate Windows Services.

I know that I can host them inside IIS with "WAS". But I am not sure of the pros and cons. (This is all about management, so I am not trying to get better performance/scalability).

I have used some SOA "solutions" before such as WebMethods. While the development experience was awful they did have some nice concepts and things you would get for free along the line of BPM, state machine monitoring, message logging and replay etc. I wonder if there is anything lightweight for Windows and .NET along those lines. Something that actually pulls together WCF, MSMQ, IIS etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) Hosting provides some of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes IIS + WAS + AppFabric is what you are looking for. It will not provide everything you want because MS is not going to provide MS BizTalk for free.